# Methods are absent in new Rebus and plugins

Tags: rabbitmq, log4net, castle-windsor, rebus

I have updated these libraries for messaging in a project to the latest versions:

- Rebus
- Rebus.RabbitMQ
- Rebus.Castle.Windsor
- Rebus.Log4Net
- Castle.Windsor

I was very confused when found that some of very convenient old methods are missing in this versions.

I have the following rebus configuration api:

```
 Configure.With(new WindsorContainerAdapter(container))
        .Logging(l => l.Log4Net())
        .Transport(t => t.UseRabbitMqAndGetInputQueueNameFromAppConfig(connectionString)
        .ManageSubscriptions().SetPrefetchCount(5))
        .MessageOwnership(d => d.FromRebusConfigurationSection())
        .Serialization(s => s.Use(new MySerializer()))
        .CreateBus()
        .Start();
```

These methods are absent in the new version:

- UseRabbitMqAndGetInputQueueNameFromAppConfig
- ManageSubscriptions in RabbitMqOptionsBuilder
- MessageOwnership in RebusConfigurer
- Log4Net extension methods is present in library not even recognized by VS

The Rebus documentation though still has references on old methods and scenarios in many places.

What has been done with old convenient methods? Has anybody had the same problem and could give me a hint what apis to use in the current version (0.99.67) for existing way of configuring a client.

Comment: Your best bet may be to [raise an issue](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebus versions up to and including 0.84.0 are "Rebus 1" - Rebus received a pretty big update (a rewrite of the core, followed by porting most libs forwards) in version 0.90.0 - "Rebus 2"

So your best bet is probably to `Update-Package Rebus -Version 0.84.0` (and do the same to the RabbitMQ, Windsor, and Log4net integration packages)

Rebus 2 is not compatible with Rebus 1, so if you decide to update to 2, you should be aware of that.

Moreover (as you have discovered) it has seen a couple of API changes, where the most significant change is that most methods on `IBus` are now `async` and thus requires that you e.g `await bus.Send(...)` (or `bus.Send(...).Wait()` if you are not in an `async` method)

Comment: Thank you for a answer. I am new to Rebus and messaging. Could you give me a hint where to read about what and how should i use instead of old methods Also is it still possible to use something in new Rebus instead of UseRabbitMqAndGetInputQueueNameFromAppConfig - to read queue name from rebus config, what should i use instead of ManageSubscriptions and MessageOwnership(d => d.FromRebusConfigurationSection()

Comment: Yes definitely - check it out here: https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/issues/490#issuecomment-232889458

Comment: Hi @TakinosaJi - if you are satisfied with the answer, could you please mark the question as answered?